# Export/Import a 3D file format with Textures

Tags: graphics3d, export, 3d-printing, textures

In version 12.1, the docs say that it is now possible to export/import to a 3D file format while ***preserving textures***:

[image: formats]

But I can't seem to find *a single example* of this new feature!

**Code to try:**

If you can figure out how get the texture on the exported cube, you've solved this problem. Here's a test:

```
vtc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
coords = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
     0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 
     1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 
     1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 
     1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}};
Export["~/Downloads/test.fbx", 
 Graphics3D[{Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}]], 
   Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[vtc, {6}]]}]]
SystemOpen@%
```

[image: example]

- The FBX format can contain textures (for most other formats apps typically output textures as images into a directory).
- Perhaps there is a way to generate an associated MTL file?
- It looks like ["STL"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html) itself, according to Wikipedia, doesn't support textures inherently.

Comment: While I can see how colors can be represented, it doesn’t seem like the “STL” format even supports textures? Though it may come down to how one defines textures. If this refers to materials, then the format should support it.

Comment: But FBX does, I've used .vrml in the past (with other apps).

Comment: I think .blend, .glb, and 3Dpdf all support embedded image textures, but those are not in $ExportFormats, @CATrevillian do you know of any other?

Comment: So, several things: `FBX` is not listed under the list of all 3D geometry formats, though it is of course included in that of `$ImportFormats` and `$ExportFormats`. When you take a look further down on the reference page for `FBX`, under `Import Elements`>`”BinaryFormat”`, it references `STL` so that might be one possible source of this claim of an updated `STL`. `DAE` makes the same claim as that of `FBX` as to optionally storing textures. None of the other mentioned formats seem to have been updated, and `FBX` is the only one to indicate it is new in the footer of the reference page.

Comment: I was pretty certain that STL doesn't support textures directly and any ways to support it are non-standardized.

Comment: It's possible to export texture mapping embeded with obj file. One needs to generate the texture index triangles and convert it into obj format string.

Comment: @HyperGroups please give a code example

Comment: I think this has to be a typo -- maybe this was meant for a different format?. STL does not support textures, and the support of _face_ colors is not standardized. Also STL is a face set format, and so there's no way to store vertex information, like color, cleanly. STL _does_ support face normals, but funnily enough WL does not export them, which is why the lighting in the Preview screenshot looks ambient.